# req.user is undefined when trying to get it from api methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have two files in `routes` folder - `index.js` and `api.js`.
`index.js` only sends the main template page with linked styles, images and scripts.
`api.js` manages all the API calls.

I am implementing authentication with PassportJS. Authentication itself works fine. The issue is that for some reason I get `undefined` when trying to access `req.user` from `api.js` endpoints, but it is fine and filled with proper data when accessed from `index.js`.

For example, I need to send as JSON all user's posts when requested from api endpoint so I want to get `req.user.id` or something like this to send a request to database on server side.

What could I miss while configuring Passport?

Comment: passport deserialize the user with the help of the session id in your cookie, maybe you don't send the cookie, or there's something wrong with your session.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the passport's session middleware **before** all your routes so it can set `req.user`.

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(myRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're getting .**_id** instead of **.id**, this is the default ID creation in MongoDB.